siamese neural network (machine learning)
I am trying to train a siamese neural network but I encounter this error whenever I run the train.py file
Successful Load Key: [] ……
Successful Load Key Num: 0

Fail To Load Key: ['features.0.weight', 'features.0.bias', 'features.2.weight', 'features.2.bias', 'features.5.weight', 'features.5.bias', 'features.7.weight', 'features.7.bias', 'features.10.weight', 'features.10.bias', 'features.12.weight', 'features.12.bias', 'features.14.weight', 'features.14.bias', 'features.17.weight', 'features.17.bias', 'features.19.weight', 'features.19.bias', 'features.21.weight', 'features.21.bias', 'features.24.weight', 'features.24.bias', 'features.26.weight', 'features.26.bias', 'fe ……
Fail To Load Key num: 32

This is loading code：
model = Siamese(input_shape, pretrained)
    if model_path != '':
        if local_rank == 0:
            print('Load weights {}.'.format(model_path))
        model_dict = model.state_dict()
        pretrained_dict = torch.load(model_path, map_location=device)
        load_key, no_load_key, temp_dict = [], [], {}
        for k, v in pretrained_dict.items():
            if k in model_dict.keys() and np.shape(model_dict[k]) == np.shape(v):
                temp_dict[k] = v
                load_key.append(k)
            else:
                no_load_key.append(k)
        model_dict.update(temp_dict)
        model.load_state_dict(model_dict)
        if local_rank == 0:
            print("\nSuccessful Load Key:", str(load_key)[:500], "……\nSuccessful Load Key Num:", len(load_key))
            print("\nFail To Load Key:", str(no_load_key)[:500], "……\nFail To Load Key num:", len(no_load_key))

I saw several posts talking about nn.Dataparallel but I am not exactly sure how to go about that. I am kind of new to machine learning

Since all the keys supposedly failed to load, the code sample could be simplified to show how the dict of loaded keys was retrieved and how the list of other keys was conceived.
